# How to use ag-grid-react in a React CDN App

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

I want to use Ag Grid React as a CDN, and I have the following setup on codepen as a sample to what's in my local project: https://codepen.io/oosharma/pen/OJzLBKg

When trying to load a basic <AgGridReact.AgGridReact> component, I am getting the error at ag-grid-react.min.js:1 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bool')

Here is the CodePen code copied here-

```js
const App = () => {
  const [rowData] = [{
      make: "Toyota",
      model: "Celica",
      price: 35000
    },
    {
      make: "Ford",
      model: "Mondeo",
      price: 32000
    },
    {
      make: "Porsche",
      model: "Boxter",
      price: 72000
    }
  ];

  return ( <
    div className = "ag-theme-alpine"
    style = {
      {
        height: 400,
        width: 600
      }
    } >
    <
    AgGridReact.AgGridReact rowData = {
      rowData
    } >
    <
    AgGridReact.AgGridColumn field = "make" > < /AgGridReact.AgGridColumn> <
    AgGridReact.AgGridColumn field = "model" > < /AgGridReact.AgGridColumn> <
    AgGridReact.AgGridColumn field = "price" > < /AgGridReact.AgGridColumn> < /
    AgGridReact.AgGridReact > <
    /div>
  );
};

let domContainer = document.querySelector("#root");
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , domContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ag-grid/Docs-27.0.1-20220211/ag-grid-community.min.js"></script>
<script src=" https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-react@23.0.0/umd/ag-grid-react.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```